# Google Maps Delete Marker with it's id

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map with a lot of of Markers and their Circles. I have Successfully added Markers and Circles and saved their id. But Deleting Marker is easy but deleting circle is making a problem even though i have the id of Circle what's the method to find that Circle ?

```
   like **googlemap.getCircle(id).remove();**
```

But there is no method like this so how can i do that?? I am thinking on Clearing the map and adding All the markers and Circles again,
EDIT- here is my code.

```
         String mid =  marker.getId();
            DataBaseOperations hell = new DataBaseOperations(getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = hell.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.query(mDatabase.Table, new String[]{mDatabase.ID}, mDatabase.ID, new String[]{mid}, null, null, null);
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                String cid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.cid));
            }
            marker.remove();
            hell.close();
            db.close();
            c.close();
```

cid is the id of Circle, added previously now how can i delete this circle using it's id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your circle with your circle_function object, like this:

```
Circle mapCircle{
//your circle method, 
//**example**
}

/* to remove your cirlce call remove() method**/
mapCircle.remove();
```

Comment: Couldn't understand bro.

Comment: Try to delete your circle using remove() method.

Comment: yo are not understanding dude.